# jQuery UI autocomplete no response bind or select is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Jquery autocomplete for textbox search is not working ,webservice is called but the value is not binded to the textbox .please let me know what's wrong in this code.
**.aspx page:**

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbStudentName" runat="server" class="tbStudentName" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnStudentSearch" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnSearch" OnClick="btnStudentSearch_Clicked"  />
```

Script:

```
function AutoCompleteName(target) {
var xhr;

$j("." + target.className).autocomplete({

    source: function (request, response) {

        if (xhr && xhr.readystate != 4) {
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $j.ajax({
            url: "../ServiceInterface/StudentLookupService.asmx/StudentSearch",
            data: "{'pStudentId': '', 'pStudentName': '" + request.term + "'  }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($j.map(data.d, function (item) {

                    return {
                        label: item.StudentId + ' : ' + item.LastName + ', ' + item.FirstName + ' ' + item.MiddleName,
                        value: item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName

                    }
                }))

            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                response([]);
            }
        });

    },

    select: function (event, ui) 
    {

        $j("." + target.className).val = ui.item.firstName + ' ' + ui.item.lastName;
        return true;
    },
    minLength: 1

});
```

}
Also when i enter two character in search box am getting error function,for 3 or more characters only the web service is called.

Please let me know your suggestions to make it work

Comment: I suspect you'll resolve this issue on your own if you step through your `success: function(data) { /* ... */ }` block. Is the block being reached? If so, what's `data` look like? Are you correctly mapping to it?

Comment: yes am getting data in success block .got student id and name verified it by alert message

Comment: Also, is the "error function" an HTTP error? Or is it just a plain old validation error? Either way, it's good practice to do 3 character limits on the auto-complete unless you're data set is going to be small / constant.

Comment: the major problem is result value is not bind to the control .Am i need to change anything here for binding

Comment: I think your issue might be that you are returning an object - `{ key : foo, value : bar }` and not an [array, string or function.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). Try returning an array of objects: `[{ key: foo, value: bar }];`